# Isomorphism passes on to a direct summand?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra

Let $\mathcal{T}$ be an additive category (or Abelian category, triangulated category). Take objects $A_1, A_2, B_1$ and $B_2$ in $\mathcal{T}$ such that there are morphisms $a_1:A_1 \to B_1$ and $a_2:A_2 \to B_2$ and $A_1$ (resp. $B_1$) is a direct summand of $A_2$ (resp. $B_2$). Let $i$ (resp. $j$) denote the split injective $A_1 \hookrightarrow A_2$ (resp. $B_1 \hookrightarrow B_2$) and let $d$ (resp. $e$) denote the split surjective $A_2 \to A_1$ (resp. $B_2 \to B_1$). We assume $j \circ a_1 =a_2\circ i$ and $e\circ a_2 = a_1\circ d$.

If $a_2$ is an isomorphism, then is $a_1$ also an isomorphism?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $\ a_1\ $ is an isomorphism too. **Indeed**:

isomorphism $\ \alpha_2: B_2\to A_2\ $ inverse to $\ a_2\ $ is given
as an assumption; and let

$$ \alpha_1\ :=\ d\circ \alpha_2\circ j $$

These two newly named morphisms, and the ones that appear in the original formulation, are bounded by the following identities:

- $\qquad e\circ j=1_{B_1} $
- $\qquad d\circ i=1_{A_1} $
- --
- $\qquad \alpha_2\circ a_2=1_{A_2} $
- $\qquad a_2 \circ\alpha_2=1_{B_2} $
- --
- $\qquad j\circ a_1 = a_2\circ i $
- $\qquad a_1\circ d = e\circ a_2 $

The problem will be solved by proving $\ \alpha_1\circ a_1=1_{A_1}\ $ and $\ a_1\circ\alpha_1=1_{B_1} $,

$$ \alpha_1\circ a_1\ =\ d\circ\alpha_2\circ j\circ a_1 =
        d\circ\alpha_2\circ a_2\circ i = d\circ i\ =\ 1_{A_1} $$
and
$$ a_1\circ\alpha_1\ =\ a_1\circ d\circ\alpha_2\circ j =
        e\circ a_2\circ\alpha_2\circ j = e\circ j = 1_{B_1} $$
-- **done.**

Comment: @LSpice, thank you for correcting my multi-letter TeX typo -- it was an intermediate, temporary extra string under edition (I was not even able to see it, I "saw" only the way it was supposed to be).